# Mysql query does not return the columns of the 2nd joined table

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

Why the following sql query does not return all the columns of the second table named **comments** but instead ONLY the ID column of the **wp_users** table ?

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN (select * from wp_comments) as comments
ON ID = comments.user_id
WHERE comments.comment_type = 'user_course'
```

If I change the query to the following statement it works as it should be which means all columns of the 1st and the 2nd table which of course are matching the WHERE criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN (select * from wp_comments) as comments
ON ID = comments.user_id
WHERE comments.comment_type = 'user_course'
```

Comment: SELECT ID FROM ... doing what you asked it to.  If you want anything else, you must ask for it as well.

Comment: `select ID, comments.* from...`

Comment: I am refering to 1st query example. ID = is returned ok but I get not results from the 2nd table with "select * from wp_comments". Why ?

Comment: @Maverick i have added explanation at my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query is invalid. You make extra select inside `INNER JOIN` which create new temporary table. Then you make join with this table. The fields from this temporary table will not automatically selected into query results. You should specify set of fields you want to select. So, you may make join directly with `wp_comments` table and add all fields from this table to resulting fields set with `c.*`. All query should be like this:

```
SELECT w.id, c.* 
FROM wp_users w 
INNER JOIN wp_comments c on c.user_id = w.ID
   and c.comment_type = 'user_course'
```

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I have added explanation.

Comment: Ok, so why almost the same query works as expected in the 2nd example ?

Comment: What second example do you mean? If you mean your example, the because of `*` which means "select all fields from joined tables". If you talking about my example then because of `c.*` which means all fields from table c (the alias for `wp_comments`)

Comment: Thanks, I refer to my examples. So to finalize you say with a few words that: In the 1st query ALL fields are selected BUT ONLY id field is displayed. In the 2nd example ALL fields are also selected AND ALL fields are displayed. Correct  ?

Comment: I just did some tests. It seems that my (which is your suggestion) previous conclusion just above is correct.